# Accessing session outside of Service creates duplicate

Tags: session, servicestack, jwt

In my request filter I'm setting some properties in a custom session which I later access from the service. This works as expected.

Request Filter:

```
public sealed class CustomAttribute:RequestFilterAttribute
{

    public override void Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        var session = req.SessionAs<CustomSession>();

        if (!session.FromToken)
        {
            throw new AuthenticationException("Please authenticate using bearer token or with flag 'UseTokenCookie' set to true.");
        }

        ... do some work ...

        session.X = tup.Item2;
        session.Y = tup.Item1;
        req.SaveSession(session);

    }
}
```

In my service:

```
var session = this.SessionAs<CustomSession>();
var myX = session.X;
var myY = session.Y;

... do some work ...

var someObj = new MyOtherClass();
someObj.DoSomeWork();
```

Later in the same request, I tried to access these same properties and was returned a different session.

```
public class MyOtherClass
{
    ...stuff...
    public void DoSomeWork()
    {
        ...
        var req = HostContext.AppHost.TryGetCurrentRequest();
        var session = req.SessionAs<CustomSession>(); //-> this returns a new session?
        var myX = session.X; //-> so this is null
        var myY = session.Y; //-> and this is null

    }
}
```

My question is why? It's the same request. What am I doing wrong?

For context - I'm using JWT (as of 4.5.6) and 'MyOtherClass' is actually a singleton error handling class which decides when a failure is significant enough to fail a transaction or trigger an email notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not accessing the same `IRequest` instance when you use `HostContext.TryGetCurrentRequest()`, it creates a new instance for the ASP.NET Request which needs to re-fetch the session from the cache.

You'll either need to pass the same base.Request instance in your Service (recommended) which will let you access the same locally-cached session instance or you can save the session after you make changes using `IRequest.SaveSession()` that way when the session is re-fetched it will load the modified session. If you're using the default MemoryCacheClient you'll incur no I/O costs.